# .NetCore 3-tier: How to write API get list DepartmentName: number of employee in Department?, using Linq method syntax

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, get, entity-framework-core

---

I want write API get All DepartmentName have total emoloyee in department, I have two table Department (ID, Name), Employee (ID, UserId,UserName,..). My code as below and this false:

```
       var entity = unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetAll();
       var groupentity = entity.Join(unitOfWork.DepartmentRepository.GetAll(), 
                                             user => user.Id, dept => dept.Id,
                                             (user, dept) => new
                                                          {
                                                           DeptName = dept.Name,
                                                           UserCount = user.UserId.Count()                                                                
                                                          }).ToDictionary(d => d.DeptName, d => d.UserCount);
       return groupentity;
```

---

i want result like:

| Department Name | number employee |
| --- | --- |
| Dev | 10 |
| Data | 5 |

---

pls, help! thank you

Comment: Maybe this can help : [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

i'll suppose you have a property named DepId in User

```
            var groupentity = entity.Join(unitOfWork.DepartmentRepository.GetAll(),
                                  user => user.DepId, dept => dept.Id,
                                  (user, dept) => new
                                  {
                                      DeptName = dept.Name,
                                      UserCount = user.Id
                                  }).GroupBy(d => d.DeptName, (key, group) => new { DepartmentName = key, NumberEmployee = group.ToList().Count }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, suppose i put it in method in DepartmentManager.cs, how to i call it int DepartmentController?

Comment: its up to how your application working , maybe with DI or any other solution ... if you would to share the code of your files , i'll help you